# Reverse-engineering a Javascript chat

Tags: javascript, tcp, reverse-engineering, burp

This is the case.

I'm reverse-engineering a chat. The client runs in a browser, in Javascript.
Nothing is documented, but by checking the HTTP requests/responses (using Burp Suite), I've been able to figure out everything.

For simplicity, let's say that "everything" means loading the last messages and also sending a message.

However, the chat client detects "events". E.g., when a new message arrives. And I'm pretty sure the program **is not** polling any endpoint for this.

So, there should be an existing active connection receiving these events.

I am sure it's not WebSockets. So I need to look elsewhere, and checking the Javascript code (which is fragmented, obfuscated and minified) seems to be a HUGE task without knowing what to look for.

I've used Wireshark / mitmproxy for clues but could not get anything more useful that what I get with Burp.

What's the cheapest route to find out where is this program connecting to? I'm not much versed in Javascript so I don't know what are the ways of connecting to a given host and receiving events.

Any hints?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Open the browser devtools, look at the network tab? (this approach is almost always easier than using tools outside the browser like Wireshark)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I did that. Nothing happens apart of the usual XHR requests.
On incoming messages, a request is made to "acknowledge" the message reception (i.e., from the chat client to the server). But before that, nothing comes from server to client.

Answer (score 1):

As weird as it may sound, the events were hidden behind a default filter.
They come as *text/event-stream*, which is strangely recognized as CSS by Burp.